# Check to see if date is valid somewhere in the world

Tags: python, date, timezone, timestamp

How can one check if a given timestamp still holds somewhere in the globe?

For instance, say that I have a timestamp similar to May 10, 2017, 3:49pm. Is there any place in the world today for which is May 10, 2017, 3:49pm?

Comment: Do you have a language preference for this computation?

Comment: Preferably python.

Comment: When you say "somewhere in the globe", do you mean somewhere *inhabited*? Or just somewhere with a defined tzdb time zone identifier?  These aren't necessarily the same things.  Do you need to know where and/or which time zone ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if time stamp is in between UTC+14 and UTC-12.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def is_a_today_somewhere(timestamp):
  now = datetime.now()
  latest = now + timedelta(hours=-12)
  earliest = now + timedelta(hours=14)
  return  latest <= datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp) <= earliest

now = datetime.now()                        # now
timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)
print(is_a_today_somewhere(timestamp))      # prints True

now = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=7)   # +7 hours from now
timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)
print(is_a_today_somewhere(timestamp))      # prints True

now = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=-23) # -23 hours from now
timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)
print(is_a_today_somewhere(timestamp))      # prints False
```

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/IRoE/6.js"></script>
```

Note that the check should be an inclusive between. But due to the time taken from the generation of the time-stamp to checking its validity, edge cases where the time stamp is barely at the latest timezone might come up false.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def is_a_today_somewhere(timestamp):
  now = datetime.now()
  latest = now + timedelta(hours=-12)
  earliest = now + timedelta(hours=14)
  return  latest <= datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp) <= earliest

now = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=-12)  # -12 hours from now; barely in today 
timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)
print(is_a_today_somewhere(timestamp))      # May print False
```

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/IRoE/8.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check by comparing the current time in all time zones to the time provided.

Here is a function that will do that for you:

```
import datetime
deviations_from_utc = (-12, -11, -10, -9.5, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5,
                   -4, -3.5, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5,
                   5.5, 5.75, 6, 6.5, 7, 8, 8.5, 8.75, 9, 9.5, 10, 
                   10.5, 11, 12 , 12.75, 13, 14)
def is_current(t):
    n = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    provided_time = (t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.minute)
    for time in deviations_from_utc:
        at = n + datetime.timedelta(hours=time)
        at_time = (at.year, at.month, at.day, at.hour, at.minute)
        if provided_time == at_time:
            return True
    return False
```

deviations_from_utc contains all of the deviations from utc time that are used. The list was taken from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) wikipedia article.

Comment: thanks for your attempt, but your function almost got it right. I guess the solution is to compare the input time (`t`) with the least possible time on Earth (UTC-12). Then, if `t` is greater or equal to `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`, then t is necessarily valid :)
This would also eliminate the need for a loop.

Comment: Ah. I must have misread it as some place on earth must have the time t, not  t will be valid somewhere sometime today.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard deviations from UTC i.e a maximum of +14 and a minimum of -12, you can compare the timestamps and see if the timestamp lies between the maximum and the minimum.

```
from datetime import datetime


def is_valid_time(search_timestamp):
    utc_timestamp = datetime.timestamp(datetime.utcnow())
    max_timestamp = utc_timestamp + (14*60*60)  # max time is utc+14
    min_timestamp = utc_timestamp - (12*60*60)  # min time is utc-12

    # check if time in range
    if min_timestamp <= search_timestamp <= max_timestamp:
        return True
    return False

# Test cases
now = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())
# false
print(is_valid_time(3))

# false
print(is_valid_time(now + (16*60*60)))

# true
print(is_valid_time(now))
```